# Read parent elements from TreeView in WPF

Tags: c#, treeview

I just want to access the parent elements of a selected child from a TreeView. It is a WPF application and I need the C# code to get the selected child and its parents as strings.The function is:

```
private void treeView1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{

//How to get the selected child and parents as strings

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you not using MVVM, the following will get you the contents of the item the user clicked on and the parent.

```
    private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        TreeView the_tree = e.OriginalSource as TreeView;

        TreeViewItem clicked_item = the_tree.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;

        MessageBox.Show(clicked_item.Header.ToString());

        TreeViewItem clicked_parent = clicked_item.Parent as TreeViewItem;

        MessageBox.Show(clicked_parent.Header.ToString());

    }
```

don't forget to add error checking, if the user clicks on the root, this will throw an exception.